# How can I stop a jQuery dialog from closing when submitting form that's inside

Tags: jquery, html, forms, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a jQuery UI dialog that contains a small form. When submitting the form it closes the dialog. This would be fine if the form is completed properly but if it isn't the validation messages appear so in the event of this I need the dialog to stay open.

The problem I have is that I am using Webassist's Dreamweaver extensions to write the php for the validation  and calls to the Database which inserts the form data which is triggered by the SUBMIT button. I somehow need to prevent the submit button from closing the dialog if the form has errors.

Here is the form that has the pre-built php code from the dreamweaver extension.

```
<form method="post" name="request" id="request" class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="control-group">
          <label for="firstname" class="control-label">First Name</label>
          <div class="controls">
            <input name="firstname" type="text" class="input-large <?php
if (ValidatedField('home_946','home_946'))  {
if ((strpos((",".ValidatedField("home_946","home_946").","), "," . "1" . ",") !== false     || "1" == ""))  {
if (!(false))  {
 ?>
              fail
              <?php //WAFV_Conditional home.php home_946(1:)
}
}
}?>" id="firstname" value="<?php echo(ValidatedField("home_946","firstname")) ?>"/>
            <?php
if (ValidatedField('home_946','home_946'))  {
if ((strpos((",".ValidatedField("home_946","home_946").","), "," . "1" . ",") !== false || "1" == ""))  {
if (!(false))  {
?>
              <p class="show-if"> Your first name is required </p>
              <?php //WAFV_Conditional home.php home_946(1:)
}
}
}?>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
          <label for="surname" class="control-label">Surname</label>
          <div class="controls">
            <input name="surname" type="text" class="input-large <?php
if (ValidatedField('home_946','home_946'))  {
if ((strpos((",".ValidatedField("home_946","home_946").","), "," . "2" . ",") !== false || "2" == ""))  {
if (!(false))  {
?>
              fail
              <?php //WAFV_Conditional home.php home_946(2:)
}
 }
}?>" id="surname" value="<?php echo(ValidatedField("home_946","surname")) ?>">
            <?php
if (ValidatedField('home_946','home_946'))  {
if ((strpos((",".ValidatedField("home_946","home_946").","), "," . "2" . ",") !== false || "2" == ""))  {
if (!(false))  {
?>
              <p class="show-if"> Your surname is required </p>
              <?php //WAFV_Conditional home.php home_946(2:)
}
}
}?>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
          <label for="email" class="control-label">Email</label>
          <div class="controls">
            <input name="email" type="text" class="input-large <?php
if (ValidatedField('home_946','home_946'))  {
if ((strpos((",".ValidatedField("home_946","home_946").","), "," . "3" . ",") !== false || "3" == ""))  {
if (!(false))  {
?>
              fail
              <?php //WAFV_Conditional home.php home_946(3:)
}
}
}?>
<?php
if (ValidatedField('home_946','home_946'))  {
if ((strpos((",".ValidatedField("home_946","home_946").","), "," . "4" . ",") !== false || "4" == ""))  {
if (!(false))  {
?>
                fail
                <?php //WAFV_Conditional home.php home_946(4:)
}
}
}?>" id="email" value="<?php echo(ValidatedField("home_946","email")) ?>">
            <?php
if (ValidatedField('home_946','home_946'))  {
if ((strpos((",".ValidatedField("home_946","home_946").","), "," . "3" . ",") !== false || "3" == ""))  {
if (!(false))  {
?>
              <p class="show-if"> Your email is required </p>
              <?php //WAFV_Conditional home.php home_946(3:)
}
}
}?>
            <?php
if (ValidatedField('home_946','home_946'))  {
if ((strpos((",".ValidatedField("home_946","home_946").","), "," . "4" . ",") !== false || "4" == ""))  {
if (!(false))  {
?>
                <p> This is not a valid email address </p>
                <?php //WAFV_Conditional home.php home_946(4:)
 }
 }
}?>
          </div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit">
      </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to validate it in JavaScript (so the popup/modal doesn't reload), you could use AJAX to do some PHP validation also.

Here is a jQuery UI example which is similar to what you want.

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form

If you are still stuck after looking at that then post up some more of your code and I will take a look.

Comment: Thanks for this, Because my knowledge of javascript/AJAX/php is limited I am using 'WebAssists' DW extensions to handle the validation. I have added the code above that is created for the validation messages.

Comment: There is also another very large PHP file created that I wouldn't want to post up above. So the code Ive given so far probably doesn't tell you enough. Sorry for this! I might try the example you gave.

Comment: Jon I've tried to adapt the code from your suggestion but I am failing. See above for my updated post. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry maybe I miss understood. When you said jQuery dialog box I though you meant the jQuery UI one. jQuery UI is a add on to jQuery which has some prebuilt feature like dialog boxes.

Comment: Are you able to post a link to the page or is it offline or behind a login section?

Comment: What fields are on the form?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63962/discussion-between-steve-joiner-and-jon).

Answer (score 0):

You can add `$('#info-request').trigger('click');` before error message(It will reopen your dialog) where you return if form is not completed properly.

Comment: As you can see in the code above, the error message is  wrapped in PHP code so how and where would I add your suggestion?